# Why am i getting a TemplateSyntaxError while trying to deploy Django using mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to setup Django with Apache under Windows. I've activated the mod_wsgi module but when I access the localhost I get an Internal Server Error and the following appears in the Apache error log:

```
[Fri Nov 26 18:20:31 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' isn't an available database backend. 
[Fri Nov 26 18:20:31 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
[Fri Nov 26 18:20:31 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3
[Fri Nov 26 18:20:31 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Error was: cannot import name utils
```

My database backend is not accepted. It works if I run the development server, and it also works if I leave the database settings as empty strings (I only have a very simple test page, just some text).

The wsgi file is the following:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/django')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/django/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server is out of available file descriptors. Reconfigure mod_wsgi for daemon mode.